# How are you supposed to use the PXDBCryptString attribute to decrypt a value

Tags: acumatica

I am using the following definition below within a DAC expecting the results to be encrypted in the database but show as decrypted in the UI or Code within a graph class. What I get as a result is it shows the encrypted value in the UI and code. I am unable to figure out how I am supposed to decrypt the value being returned.

I am trying to find more information on how to use this Attribute however the 2018R1-AcumaticaFramework-DevelopmentGuide.pdf has only sparse information on it. It has the following link [PXDBCryptLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pldai.png) https://help.acumatica.com/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=176377a7-4d01-786c-a56d-e17ccbf188f0 but the link appears to no longer be available. I am unable to find anything in the T200 documentation either.

Does anyone have any information on how to correctly decrypt a value that is using this attribute?

Thanks in advance

```
    #region C2PAPIKEY
    public abstract class c2PAPIKEY : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _C2PAPIKEY;
    //[PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true)]
    //not having any luck getting these encryption attributes to work
    //the value coming back is always encrypted regardless of the
    //IsVeiwDecrypted being set to true
    //[PXRSACryptString(50, IsUnicode = true, IsViewDecrypted = true)]
    [PXDBCryptString(50, IsUnicode = true, IsViewDecrypted = true)]
    [PXDefault("")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Click to Pay API Key")]
    public virtual string C2PAPIKEY
    {
        get
        {
            return this._C2PAPIKEY;
        }
        set
        {
            this._C2PAPIKEY = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at some examples and I believe the value has to be explicitly decrypted in cache.

This can be done in the graph with a RowSelected event handler:

```
// Make sure DAC is of the type that holds the C2PAPIKEY field
public virtual void DAC_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    PXDBCryptStringAttribute.SetDecrypted<DAC.c2PAPIKEY>(sender, e.Row, true);
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I will give this a try and let you know how I make out.

Comment: HB_Acumatica, Im sorry I am still not getting the value to decrypt. I have implemented the suggested event handler above and when running the debugger I see the method executing successfully but the end result is still a encrypted string.  I have prepaired this short screen cast depicting what I am seeing https://www.dropbox.com/s/93awpx70g6kal54/Bug382%20PXDBCryptString%20is%20not%20decrypting%20the%20value%202018-12-03_9-13-49.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Also, How did you find this? Is there a resource that shows some of this information. I mentioned a link in the original post that is no longer valid. Are you aware of a place that info may have been moved to?

Comment: You can search source code of the product from the Source Code page SM204570. SetDecrypted doesn't work in isolation, you have to get everything else right too. I'd suggest you take a look at GLConsolSetup.password, you'll find it in GLConsolReadMaint graph and GLConsolSetup DAC.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I will keep you up to date on how I make out.

Comment: I think I figured out what the problem was. I tried following how the GLConsolSetup.password was set up in source code and set our field exactly the same. The Decryption routine in the end was still returning an encrypted value. Once I dropped out the explicit field size I started to get a binary data will be truncated error leading me to look into the issue SQL side. Once I tried expanding the field size to something on the order of 255 chars everything started to work fine. So in this case we have a 32 char key needing 88 chars to store the encrypted value in the DB when only 50 whereDefined

Comment: Yeah that makes sense as I said system can be tricky so you have to get everything right, not just the decryption call itself.  255 is still very low for an encrypted field, for reference GLConsolSetup.password is 1000. I wouldn't rely on the encryption routine returning a fix number of blocks so 32=88 might not hold.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I will chage up the schema to use 1000 chars for storing the encrypted values. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered The issue I was having was that I did not grant enough room in the database to store the encrypted value.
A key of 32 chars will require 88 chars to store the full encrypted string. I had the field defined as nvarchar(50) so the encrypted value was getting truncated rendering the encryption mechanism unable to decrypt the value. 
I hope this helps someone.